# My application is not showing under location services (Settings->Privacy)

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I have developed location based application and it is able to get user's location but there is strange thing in it. Under setting->Privacy->Location Services, it is not showing my application. It is only happening with iPhone 6 Plus for other devices it is showing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8 perhaps?

Comment: No that is not a case in my application. As it is showing in other devices. I have an issue with specific device only.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Turns out I simply didn't open the app and get to the prompt to allow the location services.
As long as you don't get the prompt and confirm in the app, it will not show in the Privacy->Location list.

Comment: I got the prompt (and allowed it) and the app still doesn't show under the location list. Not in Privacy and not in the app settings.

Comment: @JozemiteApps make sure you have all three in your info.plist:
(1) Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
(2) Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
(3) Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description

Comment: It did have them. Another member of our iOS team fixed the issue; I don't know what the issue was honestly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty late to the game, but I had the same problem on an iPhone 8. The app would just not show up under location services. On other devices it was showing up fine.

The only solution that worked, after spending hours on finding a non-existent bug in my code, was to **Reset Location & Privacy** in `Settings` -> `General` -> `Reset`.

[image: iOS Settings]