# Apple App Store rejection 5.1.5: "Your app uses background location services but does not clarify the..."

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple has rejected my application with the response below...

I already added the entry for "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" and "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in the *[info.plist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list)* file, but why did Apple reject it?

> Your app uses background location services but does not clarify the
> purpose of its use in the location modal alert as required in the iOS
> Human Interface Guidelines.
>
> We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please reconfigure the UIAlertControllerStyleAlert in your code and
> specify the intended purpose of using background location in its
> message field. Resources
>
> For additional information and instructions on configuring and
> presenting an alert, see the Accessing User Data section of the iOS
> Human Interface Guidelines and the UIKit Framework Reference.

Comment: What do you have for the always usage description?

Comment: What do you see in the attached screenshot(s)?

Comment: you may want to show the screenshot at well? or at least show what you did type into you `info.plist` file?

Comment: our app has the Beacons logic integrated which always search for user location

Comment: Sure but it seems that you don't inform too clearly your intents on that to the user. You can't track users without stating it clearly.

Comment: @holex : values against the "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" is "Would like to use your current location even in Background"

"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Would like to use Your Current Location When In use"

Comment: That's why you got rejected.  The description has to say what you are going to use the user's location for.

Comment: Could you please mention dummy description here means how it should be look like ... and keeping both entries in plist file won't be any issue ?

Comment: FYI : Last time apple did accepted this application with same description..don't know what happened this time to apple

Comment: Maybe they actually looked at your description this time. It clearly conflicts with their guidelines, so change it!

Comment: @sachingupta, reading your messages, I think that is quite straightforward: _"...but __does not clarify the purpose of its use__ in the location modal alert as required in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines"_...

Comment: Apple's message is completely clear. Change the description you present to your users.

Comment: I have faced the same issue [Enter description for use of Background Location services](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26118453/4970453)

Comment: App got approved after changing to appropriate description.... Thank you all –

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription* is battery intensive. If not managed properly by the App, it can result in a bad user experience not only within the App, but also a bad user experience about using the iOS device in general.

Hence, Apple wants to know if you really need the location of the user even when the user is in the background.

Even our App received a rejection last week for the same reason.

We didn't even need to submit a new binary. All we did was explained to the reviewer why we were using the location background mode which we had listed in our plist. We did this by uploading a video in which we explained the purpose of the location background mode. And then provided a link of this video in the resolution centre in iTunes connect. The reviewer had a look at it and later approved our app.

So you have to do a similar thing. If you need the location services background mode. Just explain it's intended purpose to the reviewer in the resolution centre. Else, just upload a new binary with the location services background mode removed from the plist.

Hope it helps.