# App Store rejection: 5.1.5 Legal: Privacy - Location Services

Tags: ios, core-location, appstore-approval

The app is getting rejected so many times by Apple, saying

> Upon further review, we still found that your app uses background location services but does not clarify the purpose of its use in the location modal alert as required in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines

What is the exact description to specify in "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"?

[image: For reference]

Comment: You have to explain *why* your app needs to track the user at all times.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you give me an example for **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948301/apple-app-store-rejection-5-1-5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: Related: *[Apple App Store rejection 5.1.5: "Your app uses background location services but does not clarify the..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948301/)*, *[Apple Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104184/)*, and *[Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71465167/)*

Comment: Related: *[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Apple documentation [mentioned here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html), your app can use the standard location service in the background if they provide services that require continuous location updates.

> You are currently enabled Location Background Mode device capability in your app.

**If you want to disable:**

Go to Xcode project background mode and:

> (located in the Capabilities tab of your project) and [disable] the Location updates mode. The code you write to start and stop the standard location services is unchanged.

Please check the reference screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an explanation of your apps needs to Info.plist.
Something like this:

Key: Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Value: MY_APP wants to use your location to associate MY_APP watermarks available in your geographical area.

Comment: @Ganesh System will take a string from your app Info.plist file with key "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" and  show it to user in alert. So Apple requires that this string should clear explain to user why your app needs in access to their location

Comment: Gushchin Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Re *"Info.plist"*: Not *"info.plist"* (all lowercase)?

Comment: OK, [maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8/44600497#44600497).