# Apple Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

We developed a dating application that requires users to enter personal information such as height. Our app was approved more than 5 times but recently got rejected over an update. We need this information because we want each profile to be consistent and not to have any half filled profiles. We also use the information that the user provides in their app to make matches for them. This is what Apple reviewers say:

> We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information that is not directly relevant to your app’s core functionality. Specifically, the following fields are required but do not appear to be directly relevant to your app’s core functionality:
>
> -Status, height, religion, community, speaks, education, career, drinks, smokes

We added an option "Prefer not to answer" in all string fields but height is something we believe is required. We still believe all is part of our core functionality but reviewer after appeal do not believe so.

I see other dating apps like Coffee Meets Bagel, Dil Mil, OkCupid requiring information during the sign-up process but their apps have been approved. I see that their functionality is the same as ours. You enter search criteria and they give back results.

If they can do it, I believe we are missing something that we over-looked. I believe they are using a grey area which we are missing in our app. I cannot add a video or else I would have attached it from another app to show you their process where they do not allow the users to go further without them choosing a criteria.

[image: Our sign-up page]

Comment: Do these other app don't have a 'prefer not to say' for height?

Comment: No one here can really help. You need to take this up with Apple. Just because some other app does something doesn't mean that yours will be approved. That's just the way it is.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Other apps do not have prefer not to say in all their fields not just height. Other apps do it, we are missing something that those apps include. I am asking here because someone might have dealt with this before

Comment: I'm strumbling with de same problem!

Answer (score -1):

[Example info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7LEN.png)

Add key “Privacy - Contacts Usage Description”
 in info.plist with string 
"This app require permission to access details"

[More information about keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW73)