# get location data when location services are off by ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, location-services

Is there any way to get location of the iPhone without demanding location services from the user? It should not be really accurate.

edit: I have no problem with implementation of location services. I try to find an alternative way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location Services not working in iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible. 
Apple has made location service abstract so you can't really see which technic is used. Thus if the user turns off the location service you can't get the location any other way.

There is however the option to check the user IP and get a very rough location.