# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value

Tags: permissions, plist, ios11, location-services

Today I got this issue via email from Apple after while uploading for review. 
I had uploaded app before one day ago with same info Plist and everything was perfect and approved by Apple.

[image]

**Has Apple changed their location services key again?**

I am using below-mentioned key with the proper description:

[image]

Comment: There is one more option `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description`. You need to set this also. And the Description string should not be empty.

Comment: @Venkadesh Thanks working perfect but the strange thing is that I am using the same plist from past 4 months and uploaded multiple versions on the app store but never faced this issue.

Comment: Full code of location access: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46902516/3024579