# iOS and Swift: CLLocationManagerDelegate not updating location coordinates beyond the first location

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Using the following code, my currentLat and currentLong are not updating beyond the first location.  locations never has more than 1 item, and it's always exactly the same.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let loc: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]
    currentLat = loc.coordinate.latitude
    currentLong = loc.coordinate.longitude
}
```

All the searching I've been doing has only shown how to get it to work if it doesn't work at all, but this DOES work, but only once.

The way I expect this to work is to continuously update the GPS coordinates and fire this delegate off whenever the location is updated.  Does the location keep updating the entire time?  I thought it would due to the terminology of "startUpdatingLocation()" and there being a "stopUpdatingLocation()."  Am I trying to use this incorrectly?

Like I said, it works for the first time, so it's loaded and started just fine, the permissions are allowed, the info.plist has the necessary entries.

Comment: Are you calling the delegate correctly in your **viewDidLoad**?

Comment: Yes, or it wouldn't be working the first time.  That's also where I have the startUpdatingLocation()

Comment: try to stop the update after first update `stopUpdatingLocation()` put it before `let loc: CLLocation` and then call the update location again.

Comment: Please have a look into given solution: [Update user location objective-c and Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32044306/3024579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to update your location, you should stop existing update once it got new location. You can use `stopUpdatingLocation()` in your `didUpdateLocations:` method to do so.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    // This should match your CLLocationManager()
    locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let loc: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]
    currentLat = loc.coordinate.latitude
    currentLong = loc.coordinate.longitude
}
```

Then call your `locManager.startUpdatingLocation()` when you need new location.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  So startUpdatingLocation() is actually only a single time use, and won't keep going in the background.  From what I read, I assumed it was going to keep updating the location and every time it did, it would execute this delegate.  This would explain why I have no problem getting the first location, but never again.  I only call startupdatingLocation() in viewDidLoad().

Comment: Exactly, It makes sense if you think about it, once you got the location, you haven't stopped it so basically is same as first update. I hope I get Green Check on this Answer, Cheers Mate :)

Comment: What? What is that? @LeoDabus Kill it now.

Comment: Most excellent.  This solves my problem.  All of the examples I ran across were only getting coordinates once, so the example wasn't clear enough for what I was trying to do.  It makes sense to me now, thanks Farhad.