# iOS App doesn't recieve location updates when in background

Tags: ios, swift, location

My app requires frequent location updates when in use and when running in the background.

I have enbabled Background Modes --> Location updates for my app but my app stops receiving location updates about 10 seconds after entering background mode.

[image]

My code:

```
func initializeLocationManager()
{
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
}

func startLocationManager()
{
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I've also added the following to the info.plist:

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664928/ios-core-location-is-not-asking-users-permission-while-installing-the-app-get) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue:

```
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get consistent updates, you might have to do any action every 5 minutes. How to do it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7/21966662#21966662).

Here is the solution from Ricky [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended):-

If your app is a location based mobile application that needs to monitor the location of the device when it has significant changes, the iOS will return you some location coordinates when the device has moved more than 500 meters from the last known location. Yes, even when the app is killed/suspended either by the user or iOS itself, you still can get the location updates.

So in order for a `locationManager` to get location update even when the app is killed/suspended, you must use the method `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, you can not use `startUpdatingLocation`.

When iOS wants to return the location update to the app, it will help you to relaunch the app and return a key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` to the app delegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

The key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` is very important and you must know how to handle it. You must create a new locationManager instance when you receive the key and you will get the location update on the locationManager delegate method `didUpdateLocations`.

Here is the sample code:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    self.shareModel = [LocationShareModel sharedModel];

    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) { 
      self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
      self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
      self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
      self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

      if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
      }

     [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];   

    }    
        return YES;
 }
```

In addition to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, I have created the locationManager instance when the app is active. Here are some code examples:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager)
        [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
    self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

I have written an article explaining on the details on how to get the location update for iOS 7 and 8 even when the app is killed/suspended. I have also uploaded the complete source code on GitHub with the steps on how to test this solution.

Please visit the following URLs for more information:-

[1. Getting Location Updates for iOS 7 and 8 when the App is Killed/Terminated/Suspended](http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended)

[2. Source Code on GitHub - Get the Location Updates Even when the iOS mobile apps is Suspended/Terminated/Killed](https://github.com/voyage11/GettingLocationWhenSuspended)

Comment: Thanks for you feedback.