# Will deployment target iOS 8.1 run on iPhone 4 iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, target

If i publish an app in the App Store with deployment target 8.1 will it run on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2? Or does this mean that my app will not be supported for iPhone 4 anymore?

Comment: nope it simply wont .It will be visible on the app store. But it will say requires ios 8.1 or higher in the details.

Comment: This question was already answered and explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568572/whats-the-meaning-of-base-sdk-ios-deployment-target-target-and-project-in-xc

Comment: I couldn't find this post at the time @JorgeVicenteMendoza. Thanks for pointing out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know with my android history, You can run it on target version or higher so that would be a no to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in [StackOverflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568572/whats-the-meaning-of-base-sdk-ios-deployment-target-target-and-project-in-xc)

The base SDK is what you build your app against (i.e. include and library files and frameworks). As you say, it doesn't effect the deployment target, except that base sdk >= deployment target.

You specify build settings on 2 levels as each project can have multiple targets and you might not want the same settings for all targets. The project-level settings override the default settings and the target-level settings override the project-level settings.

For example I have projects with both OSX and iOS targets and some are ARC and some are MRR. I'd have to have different projects for each if I was unable to specify build settings with the level of granularity that Xcode allows.