# .ipa file does not install in some iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I have created an app for iphone and ipad. App install perfectly in iphone but does not install in some iphone. I have use xcode for this app and already add UDID in apple's site for developing. I am using iphone-4 for testing and works fine in developing mode. I am new in ios. So I think, I forget any step for installing. Please write in step wise if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be check your verson compablity

Comment: How did you install? Xcode or what?

Comment: can you tell me how to check it?

Comment: @anhtu after build code in xcode I use itunes for installing app

Comment: Did you try with Testflight? And more you should export .ipa file with Distribution Certificate

Comment: @anhtu thanks for reply. I have use UDID. Is this process to Distribution Certificate?

Comment: Set 'Code Signing Identity' to 'iOS Distribution' in 'Build Settings'. I don't know it will work or not. You post too little information.

Comment: @anhtu Actually I am new in this field. If you want to know any details please tell me. You are talking about xcode build settings.

Comment: You should search for some tutorial about Testflight. Like this http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your Project Info in your Xcode.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev4c7.png)

Make sure the iOS Version of your iPhone is equal or bigger than the target value in your project

Comment: Here is a link [What's the meaning of Base SDK, iOS deployment target, Target, and Project in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568572/whats-the-meaning-of-base-sdk-ios-deployment-target-target-and-project-in-xc)