# Build app for IOS 9.3 and 10.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, ios9.3

I'm fairly new to iOS app development. I have had a quick look but can't find an answer but sorry in advance if this is a duplicate.

I have an iOS app developed in Swift 2.3 using the 9.3 SDK but I also want it to work on 10.0. I have set the Base SDK as 9.3 but not sure if there is anything I have to do for it to work on 10, and how would I gain access to the 10.0 features?

Comment: Don't set the base SDK to 9.3, set the base SDK to 10 and set the deployment target to 9.3

Comment: By setting Deployment Target to iOS version makes it able to work on that version so just do it .

Comment: check this link for better help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568640/3400991

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Base SDK to the latest OS use new features available in the current iOS release.  Set the Deployment Target to the oldest iOS version on which you want your app to deploy.

Make sure to test on an actual iOS device running the Deployment Target iOS version to check whether you use any newer APIs without first checking for their availability on a device running that iOS version,  The iOS Simulator is not reliable as a test for this purpose.